# How to create dynamic label and button on run time in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, button, label, selection

I have to create a label and button that always be centered align, user will select different item in any sequence and whenever user select an option it should be displayed in a line with a label and a cross button. when user will tap on cross button then that option will be deselected and remaining labels and buttons will set their position in center.

You may get a good idea with the following image[image]

[image]
[image]
see "Hers" with a "X" button. here all the selected options will come

kindly guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I'm just that cool a person, I decided to devote some time on this issue for you :)

Download an example from my Dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6487838/FSButtonLabelTest.zip

I'll explain the code a bit here later today.

**Edit:** Added some animations.

Comment: Awhh!! i really want the same thing this is awesome. thanx so nice of you

Comment: File not found on given link

Answer (score 1):

Adding a lable

```
UILabel *myLabel  =  [[UILabel alloc]init];
myLabel.frame     =  CGRectMake(50,100,100,20);
myLabel.text      =  @"Your_Text";
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

Adding a custom button with image

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame     =  CGRectMake(210, 100, 20, 20);
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removeFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

replace the removeFunction in the button target wiht your function.. If you are not sure of the coordinates of the button or label then first go into IB and place a button where you want it to be and then in the right side check the coordinates of button in show the size inspector and use those coordinates in your code this will give you a fair idea about where your button will go after you add it programmatically... hope this will help you

Comment: now how you can say that these are dynamically centered align?

Comment: well they are dynamic but not exact center aligned that thing you have to calculate according to settings of your view as you know that worksapce dimension is 320X460

Answer (score 0):

```
   UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    UIButton *btn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,200,200)];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
```